# Android - Kill Bound Activity on Service Destroy

Tags: android, service, process

I have an activity that has:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to LocalService
    exampleService = new Intent(this, exampleService.class);
    bindService(exampleService, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    startService(exampleService);
}
```

Now If I go to Manage Applications and check running services and kill the service, the activity is still running as a background process.

How can I have it so the activity that is bound to the service is killed also on destroy?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in android when you start a service then you need to manually stop that service before you kill bound any activity. So try to stop that service inside `onStop()` or `Onpause()` method.

Visit this http://androidtutorial4u.blogspot.in/p/forum.html
We have started new forum in which you can ask your questions regarding android as well as answer the questions.

Comment: Are you referring to the onStop or onPause method of the Service? or Activity? Because I need the service to kill the activity when it is killed in the Android task manager.